# How to pass multiple properties files for multiple web applications in single docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker application which is pulling tomcat image and deploying multiple (4 apps) web applications each one having property file, I need to pass property file for each individual app when is running, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create one scripts that should be in your `ENTRYPOINT["/bin/bash","init.sh"]` This scripts having set of find and replace commands to change the value for your property file.
Now start your container with `docker run -e "deep=purple" $image_name` this property will be added in your `init.sh` and replace on desired path.
So if you start 4 container with different-different parameters than you can achieve it and same image can be used.

Hope this will help

Thank you!